# Failing to update android sdk on build machine

Tags: android, jenkins

In my CI builds run on Jenkins, I have a step that downloads the sdk if it doesn't exist on the machine, then it will download and update everything that is required.  I have the build working on my macbook, and on a fresh vagrant ubuntu machine, but when I run it on the Jenkins host, it always fails.

I have this in a shell script that should download all the necessary android tools I need.

```
expect -c 'set timeout -1;
spawn android update sdk --all --filter build-tools-20.0.0,platform-tools,android-20,extra-android-support,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-m2repository --no-ui;
expect {
    "Do you accept the license" {
        exp_send "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}

catch wait result
exit [lindex \$result 3]'
```

It is just an expect script that accepts the licenses automatically.  The line in question is

```
android update sdk --all --filter build-tools-20.0.0,platform-tools,android-20,extra-android-support,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-m2repository --no-ui
```

The output on the build machine is ...

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-20.0.0'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'android-20'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'
```

Those ID's exist inside the sdk, so I am kind of lost, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments from [Xavier Ducrochet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218257/xavier-ducrohet) on a [Google+ Post](https://plus.google.com/101836723454902363467/posts/hk3LYhQGenT).

> Older version (<23) use a different XML schema for the component listing and therefore hit a different URL to get the component list. This list does not include API 20.
>
> Upgrade the tools to 23, and then run your script again it should work.﻿

I simply needed to upgrade the tools to version 23 and everything worked as expected.